# Asp.NET Identity stopped working on Chrome

Tags: asp.net, google-chrome, cookies, asp.net-identity

For some unknown reason, I no longer can log in into my own application on Chrome.

This is how I'm doing signing in:

```
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<ActionResult> Login(LoginModel model)
    {
        if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");

        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            return View();

        var status = await signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(model.Login, model.Password, true, false);
        switch (status)
        {
            case Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Owin.SignInStatus.Success:
                {
                    int userId = User.Identity.GetUserId<int>();
                    if (userManager.IsFirstLogin(userId))
                    {
                        return RedirectToAction("Declaration", "Home", new { returnUrl = model.ReturnUrl });
                    }

                    return RedirectToLocal(model.ReturnUrl);
                }
            default:
                return View();
        }
    }
```

I debugged the code and PasswordSignInAsync succeeds, however Chrome shows no cookies set for the page. In effect redirection to action, which is marked with [Authorize] attribute redirects again to login page.

I tested site on IE and everything works correctly, I can log in and out and the cookie is being set correctly.

If I can provide more detailed information, just tell me.

---

**Edit:** More details

I've been testing a piece of application, which is date-time sensitive (stops displaying after specific date). I changed system time to 01 August 2016, logged in and then switched back to now. That was when everything stopped working.

What is curious, when I switch back to that future time, I can log in again and session cookie is being set correctly. But when I return to "now", I can not log in again.

Comment: Does Fiddler trace show anything different when using Chrome vs IE?

Comment: Hi @Spook, have you worked this out? I'm facing similar problem

Comment: @RicoW I eventually did, but that was loooong time ago :) From what I remember, I had to force wipe browser's cache for that site.

Comment: hello - does anyone know a proper fix for this?

Answer (score 0):

Still need to investigate whats going on, however for me the "fix" was to change Auth cookie's name.

in Startup.Auth.cs:

```
app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
{
    AuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie,
    LoginPath = new PathString("/Account/Login"),
    CookieName = $"SomeCustomNameForAuthCookie",
    Provider = ...
});
```

I suspect the fact, that there is a lot of webs for development on my computer and all with the same default cookie name.

Comment: this didn't work for me. Using Owin 4.1 and chrome 84

Comment: Hard to tell, do you have any other projects registered in you local IIS? Does it occur also when you publish app somewhere? Don't you accidentelly exceed cookie size (as far as I remember 2kB)?

Answer (score 0):

I have same problem in my app but in my case my app is opened inside iframe and when logging in cookies are not set into browser due to which error occured and the version of chrome which is greater than 80 changes there cookies policy.We need to set this code in web.config file

```
<httpCookies sameSite="None" requireSSL="true" />
```